# Парсер XMLreader нужно получить атрибут вложенного тэга

Tags: php, mysql, xml, парсер

В общем проблема такая нужно внутри тэга ... получить атрибуты вложенного тэга . 
Как обратиться к тэгам внутри тэга? Мне нужно попасть внутрь сперва тэга content затем в directors_list -> person и получить данные всех id полей.

```
 <content id="1">  
 <actors_list person="" />
  <types_list>
    <type id="3" />
  </types_list>
 <directors_list>
    <person name="Роман Просвирнин" id="23995" />
  </directors_list>
   <geo_filters>
    <country name="Россия" id="1" code="RU" />
    <country name="Казахстан" id="5" code="KZ" />
    <country name="Киргизия" id="6" code="KG" />
    </geo_filters>
    </content>
```

Вод мой код.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();

if (!$reader->open("content.xml")) {
 die("Ошибка открытия файла 'content.xml'");
}
while ($reader->read()) {
 if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'content') {

    echo $contentId = $reader->getAttribute('id') . "\n";


    while ($reader->name === 'directors_list') {



            $reader->read();


            while ($reader->nodeType !== XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) {
                $reader->read();

                if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'person') {

                    $personsId = $reader->getAttribute('id');

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO content_director (content_id, director_id)
                VALUES ('$contentId','$personsId')";
                    mysql_query($sql);


                }
            }

    }
    }
    }
    $reader->close();
```

Comment: у вас content без id. Что вы в базу будете вставлять?

Comment: Упс... Не напечатал id.. на самом деле у каждого content есть свой id

Comment: а почему вы используете xmlreader - файл большой? можно, в этом случае, загрузить нужный фрагмент в simplexml, будет проще разбираться

Comment: да xml огромный в 600 метров

Comment: Тока добрался до компа, если еще не разобрались, смотрите. Там половину скобок можно убрать, но я сделал, как у вас было

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
$string = '<content id="1">  
 <actors_list person="" />
  <types_list>
    <type id="3" />
  </types_list>
 <directors_list>
    <person name="Роман Просвирнин" id="23995" />
  </directors_list>
   <geo_filters>
    <country name="Россия" id="1" code="RU" />
    <country name="Казахстан" id="5" code="KZ" />
    <country name="Киргизия" id="6" code="KG" />
    </geo_filters>
    </content>';

$reader = new XMLReader();

if (!$reader->xml($string)) {
 die("Ошибка открытия файла 'content.xml'");
}
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'content') {
        echo ($contentId = $reader->getAttribute('id')) . "\n";
        while ($reader->read()) {
            if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'directors_list') {
                while ($reader->read()) {
                    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'person') {
                        echo ($personsId = $reader->getAttribute('id')) . "\n";   
                        echo $sql = "INSERT INTO content_director (content_id, director_id) VALUES ('$contentId','$personsId')";
                        }
                    else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'person') { 
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'directors_list') { 
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    else if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'content') { 
        break;
        }
    }
$reader->close();
```

[Демо на eval.in](https://eval.in/419686)

Answer (score 0):

```
$parser = simplexml_load_file( 'path_to_xml' );

$parser->{ 'node1' }->{ 'node2' } ...
```